# GitLab Multiple Project CI setup

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I have a codebase that spans multiple repositories with hierarchical dependencies between them. When a breaking change goes into a dependency, it will break the CI for dependent projects. One way that we attempted to address this is to allow projects to only depend on named tags that are explicitly listed inside the repository. This prevents the breakage, but updates across repositories are quite laborious.

Is there a "standard" setup for this that alleviates some of the burden in multi-repo merges that preserves the property that you don't break the build?